# How do i save related data using entity framework asp.net mvc5?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Saving related data in entity framework is always been a challenge to me specially when I don't have a drop down list or something else to select the primary key data of primary table. So to give you more detail about what my problem, let me show you what i have in my code:
I have two models one is called Product and the second one is Review, The Product model class contains all fields for a product plus a navigation property called `Review` as seen below. Worth to be mention that there is a one to many relation ship set on Product and Reviews table where a Product can have many Reviews.

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
        public Boolean ProductIsUnlimited { get; set; }
        public Boolean ProductAvailable { get; set; }
        public Boolean DiscountAvailable { get; set; }
        public byte[] MainPicture { get; set; }
        public string MainPictureMimeType { get; set; }
        public byte[] SecondPicture { get; set; }
        public string SecondPictureMimeType { get; set; }
        public byte[] ThirdPicture { get; set; }
        public string ThirdPictureMimeType { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
```

And the Review model contains all the fields required for a review as seen below.

```
public class Review
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public int ReviewId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

I have controller called `ProductController` and on that controller i defined a `ViewResult` method to fetch a Product from database and then all the reviews which is related to that product of course using `Review` navigation property which is on Product Model. Here the method `ProductDetails`

```
public ViewResult ProductDetails(int productId)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
               .Include(p => p.Reviews)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
            return View(product);
        }
```

So that i have a view for above method where it display product details and reviews, the reviews placed in a partial view and i called in ProductDetails main view. Then i have a another partial view by the name _CreateReview where a form resides in this partial with some script for creating a new review as seen here.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductID)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Subject)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body)
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

    <script>
        var url = '@Url.Action("CreateReview", "Product")';
        var reviews = $('#reviews');
        var form = $('form');
        $('#Submit').click(function () {
            $.post(url, form.serialize(), function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    reviews.append($('#col-sm-12').val()); // add the new Review to the existing reviews
                    form.get(0).reset(); // reset the form controls
                }
            }).fail(function (result) {
                // oops
            });
            return false; // cancel the default submit
        });
    </script>
```

As you can see in above script I post the data to controller `CreateReview` action to save the review. Here is `CreateReview JsonResult` method.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateReview (Review review)
        {
            Review dbEntry = db.Reviews.Find(review.ReviewId);
                if (dbEntry != null)
                {
                    dbEntry.ProductID = review.ProductID;
                    dbEntry.Name = review.Name;
                    dbEntry.Subject = review.Subject;
                    dbEntry.Body = review.Body;
                }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(true);
        }
```

The problem starts from there, everything seems to work just fine the only piece of puzzle missing is that i couldn't figure out how to get the ProductID of that Product which is fetched by the `ProductDetails` view method and pass it to my `CreateReview JsonResult` to create a new review. Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Too long question just to get an ID, Ain't it? Sorry guys I am new to programming.

Comment: How are you calling _CreateReview and what model are you passing? Your CreateReview code doesn't look right if you are trying to CREATE a review - should be db.Reviews.Add(review); in there.

Comment: I am passing the Review model, what is wrong with it?

Comment: just look to the url below and you'll guess it.
http://localhost:2158/Product/ProductDetails?ProductID=191

Comment: @SteveGreene so what would you advise on that case? i am stuck!

Comment: yes i want to create a review

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateReview (Review review)
        {
            Review dbEntry = db.Reviews.Find(review.ReviewId);
                if (dbEntry != null)
                {
                    dbEntry.ProductID = review.ProductID;
                    dbEntry.Name = review.Name;
                    dbEntry.Subject = review.Subject;
                    dbEntry.Body = review.Body;
                }
            
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(true);
        }

Comment: There it is @SteveGreene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104058/discussion-between-naser-dostdar-and-steve-greene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your call to the partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_CreateReview", new Review { ProductId = @model.ProductId } )
```

Change your create routine:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateReview (Review review) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
            db.Reviews.Add(review);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(true);    
    }

    return Json(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about with this setup is, you can have your `CreateReview` Method take productID as well,

```
@Url.Action("CreateReview", "Product", new { productID = model.ProductID } )
```

and your `CreateReview` Method:

```
public JsonResult CreateReview (Review review, int productID){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain me what is productID and model.ProductID?

Comment: Have you noticed that i use the review model in my CreateReview partial? so just a guess what would be the productID?

Comment: I used them exaxactly how you used. The model in your view contains a `ProductID`, and you need that ID when you post the `Review` object to your `CreateReview` medthod. I'm suggesting you take that model parameter to the `CreateReview` method as the second parameter. `productID` is that second paremeter, could be anything, it's only a placeholder.